# HLSL: access texture x,y values algorythmically within fragment

Tags: shader, hlsl

I have an 1mn samples of audio encoded into a 1024x1024 texture, that i wish to load into GFX and show the waveform graph in a shader so that i can pan an zoom fast in the graph without rewriting many Texture2D files.

I need to access precise pixels of the texture from within the fragment code. 
i.e. I read tex.UV(0,0) to all fragments at column representing the first vertical line of shader's output, and if the green value of the tex.UV(0,0) equals the y value of the column, i draw a white dot on that fragment XY value, and i proceed through all the output fragment columns to draw a complete graph. To offset and zoom the graph instantly for example, audio samples 10,000 until 11,000 i simply offset the read position for the texture by 10,000. Please help with information i am simply confused.

Audio graph encoded into a texture, zoomed to 10x, a 2096 pixel texture can represent a 24 minute audio file at 11khz:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't know the answer to your question, I am mainly curious, what would be the output of the shader? If you are in a fragment shader I assume you have some sort of geometry already? It looks like to me you actually need to generate lines based on what you read on the texture? Wouldn't be easier to generate the points of your graph on the CPU in parallel then upload your lines for drawing? If you were using in opengl  you could do that on GPU and having a shared buffer between opengl and opencl. The reason why I mention that is because OpenCL allows more granular control for GPGPU

Comment: Actually looks like you might able to have cuda/dx11 interop http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__D3D11.html#group__CUDART__D3D11

This might allow to generate the buffer with the lines on the gpu, keep data there and push the buffer for drawing.
Using cuda you could have your texture as a flat buffer of value,make it easier to access data precisely

Comment: Hi, it's to display an audio waveforms as simple dot graphs or bar graphs. I could display many of them in graphics memory. I need to base entire columns of the output based on single pixels from rows in the input texture. Yes OpenCL is perhaps the answer. Thanks. It could be fast that way, i'll have to find how to mix a GPGPU and a graphics output, it is probably easy. I was a bit crazy to think that the texture can be offset and remapped dynamically per pixel. I thought i was just missing a simple base file for it. will see with CUDA. Thanks.

Comment: well in the end a texture is just an array of data. you just need to be careful of interpolation of the sampler. you can use a geometry shader to generate geometry/points/line on the fly, but i never used them personally so i am not sure how easy would be to do what you want. With cuda/opencl you have enough flexibility to do so. If you want to use opencl you probably need opengl, if you want to use cuda you probably need directx. even though i think there is a interop for cuda and opengl aswell. anyway interop is the keyword to search for. like cuda directx interop. good luck!

Comment: I programmed half of a cuda file previously and ran the v2f f2g fragment geom UV tex float4 pragmas a couple of times... I just have to revise the appdatabase, and the Matrix_MPV and vertex.yy kinds of amazingly easy and fun code syntax adn i will be flying! :D that's why i wrote here on the forum... will set a bounty for a Unity3d compute shader because that's veyr accesible as a general test platform.